# lxml error from .itertext() "ValueError: Input object has no element: HtmlComment"

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to iterate through the text content of a subtree using `elt.itertext()` (v3.5.0b1) as follows:

```
import lxml.html.soupparser as soupparser
import requests

doc = requests.get("http://f10.5post.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1142017").content
tree = soupparser.fromstring(doc)

nodes = tree.getchildren()

for elt in nodes:
    for t in elt.itertext():
         print t
```

But I keep getting an error saying

```
 File "src/lxml/iterparse.pxi", line 248, in lxml.etree.iterwalk.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134032)
 File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 67, in lxml.etree._rootNodeOrRaise (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:15220)
ValueError: Input object has no element: HtmlComment
```

Is there a way to skip all HTML comments? Also, what does this error actually mean?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if there's any built-in way to do it unless you use a PullParser

Comment: @AndyG I wonder why lxml trips over in this particular case. Hopefully I won't need to skip HTML comments to avoid this error though.

Comment: I have not used that library, but I think you can accomplish what you need easily with [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = '''
... <html><!-- PAGENAV POPUP -->
...     <div class="vbmenu_popup" id="pagenav_menu" style="display:none">
...             <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" border="0">
...             <tr>
...                     <td class="thead" nowrap="nowrap">Go to Page...</td>
...             </tr>
...             <tr>
...                     <td class="vbmenu_option" title="nohilite">
...                     <form action="index.php" method="get" onsubmit="return this.gotopage()" id="pagenav_form">
...                             <input type="text" class="bginput" id="pagenav_itxt" style="font-size:11px" size="4" />
...                             <input type="button" class="button" id="pagenav_ibtn" value="Go" />
...                     </form>
...                     </td>
...             </tr>
...             </table>
...     </div>
... <!-- / PAGENAV POPUP -->
... </html>'''
>>> root = etree.fromstring(doc)
>>> nodes = root.getchildren()
>>> nodes
[<!-- PAGENAV POPUP -->, <Element div at 0x10367f290>, <!-- / PAGENAV POPUP -->]
>>> for elt in nodes:
...     for t in elt.itertext():
...         print t
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1406, in lxml.etree._Element.itertext (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:48845)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2763, in lxml.etree.ElementTextIterator.__cinit__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64747)
  File "iterparse.pxi", line 219, in lxml.etree.iterwalk.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:125303)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 72, in lxml.etree._rootNodeOrRaise (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:13689)
ValueError: Input object has no element: lxml.etree._Comment
```

As you can see above

```
>>> nodes
[<!-- PAGENAV POPUP -->, <Element div at 0x10367f290>, <!-- / PAGENAV POPUP -->]
```

**Note**: getchildren is deprecated. You can use list.

```
>>> list(root)
[<!-- PAGENAV POPUP -->, <Element div at 0x10367f290>, <!-- / PAGENAV POPUP -->]
```

The nodes is a list of Element **and** comments. If you check how [itertext()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext) is working:

> Creates a text iterator. The iterator loops over **this element and all subelements**, in document order, and returns all inner text.

On the other hand if instead of iterating on the list, I was iterating directly on the root element with:

```
>>> for t in root.itertext():
...     print t
...
```

I get all the text and a lot of spaces. :)

if you still want to iterate on a list of nodes. You can infer the nature with

```
>>> [item.tag for item in nodes]
[<built-in function Comment>, 'div', <built-in function Comment>]
```

You can also do

```
>>> [item.__class__ for item in nodes]
[<type 'lxml.etree._Comment'>, <type 'lxml.etree._Element'>, <type 'lxml.etree._Comment'>]
```